BuildFastify makes Google Cloud Function not to see the function name
I am uploading my nodejs source code via Cloud Build which uses gcloud function command.  This function has failed to deploy and will not work correctly. The error I get is:
Function 'myFunction' is not defined in the provided module.
Did you specify the correct target function to execute?
Could not load the function, shutting down.. Please visit     https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting for in-depth troubleshooting documentation.

My gcloud command:
gcloud functions deploy my-cgp-function \
--set-env-vars "SERVE_MODE=GCP-FUNCTION" \
--project=my-project-xxx \
--region=europe-west2 \
--runtime=nodejs18 \
--entry-point=myFunction \
--trigger-http \
--allow-unauthenticated

Here is my nodejs code:
const buildFastify = require('./app');

global.nodeRoot = require("path").resolve(__dirname) + "/";


buildFastify().then(async (fastify) => {
  if (process.env.SERVE_MODE === 'GCP-FUNCTION') {
    module.exports = {
    myFunction: async (request, reply) => {
    await fastify.ready();
    fastify.server.emit('request', request, reply);
  }
}
  } else {
    fastify.listen(8011, "0.0.0.0", (err, address) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      fastify.log.info(`server listening on ${address}`);
});
  }
}).catch(console.error)

It seems that maybe some of the Fastify middleware modifies the request.
I tried to run this locally with the GCP Functions framework but I got the same.
I am not sure how to get around this issue.

Can you check this blog & link, also have a look at this github thread1 & thread2

Those changes in code made it work:
const buildFastify = require('./app');

global.nodeRoot = require("path").resolve(__dirname) + "/";

let fastifyBuilt;

buildFastify().then(async (fastify) => {
  fastifyBuilt = fastify;
  fastify.listen(8011, "0.0.0.0", (err, address) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    fastify.log.info(`server listening on ${address}`);
  });
}).catch(console.error)

exports.myFunction = async (request, reply) => {
  await fastifyBuilt.ready();
  fastifyBuilt.server.emit('request', request, reply);
};

